# Angular - conditionally open all links in a new tab

Tags: angularjs, iframe, angular-ui-router, window.open

I have an angular app, which some areas can be embedded into other sites via an iFrame.

In that situation, I want all links used in the iFrame to open in a new window.  The same links, when not in an iFrame should just update the route/state.

The app uses ui-router.

Is there a simple way to conditionally open all routes / state changes in a new window if the page is in an iFrame?

I have tried this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {

  if(inIFrame) {
    $window.open($state.href(toState.name, toParams, {absolute: true}), '_blank');
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
 })
```

Which kinda works, but it fires for the initial load of the app.

So, the first state change is actually firing up the route that I want to render in the iFrame - its all subsequent ones that I want to trap.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a more elegant way to do this, but what about?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {

if ($rootScope.beenHereDoneThat) {
  if(inIFrame) {
    $window.open($state.href(toState.name, toParams, {absolute: true}), '_blank');
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  else {
    $rootScope.beenHereDoneThat = true;
  } 
})
```

Comment: Iv'e ended up with something similar....    `if (fromState.name!=='')`   The `fromState` name is empty when loading the app for the first time, from then on it has a value, but effectively does what you suggested.